# How can i calculate the sum

Tags: python, dataframe, math, sum

I have a data frame that contains a list of products and their npi values.

how can i tell python to take the sum of each products npi and divide it by the sum of all the products npi?

Answer (score 1):

#### Use `.sum()` to total the values of the `npi` values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['product A', 'product B', 'product A', 'product C', 'product B'], 
        'npi': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

df['ratio'] = df['npi'] / df['npi'].sum()

print(df)
```